# Плагин модальные окна

Tags: jquery, плагин

Ищу плагин для открытия модальных окон на jquery. Плагин должен уметь открывать в модальном окне ссылку, по которой клацнул незадачливый пользователь (именно ссылку, а не скрытый div, перезапись alert и notice тоже не нужна). Подобное реализовано в галерее *FancyBox* и работает очень здорово. Хотелось бы тоже самое, но без галереи, уж больно она здоровая для такой нанозадачи.

Апнем вопрос :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a.modal').live('click', function(){
    $('body').append('<iframe src="'+this.href+'"></iframe>');
});
```

Остальное - дело стилизации.

Answer (score 0):

может подойдёт [GreyBox](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/gbx)?

Comment: Нет, увы, он только со слоями работает.

Comment: А если в этом вашем слое будет iframe?

Comment: Слой не должен использоваться. Должны быть ссылка вида:
<a href="somepage.php?some-param=1" rel="modal-window">Пыщ</a>
Ссылок таких много, если под каждую городить слой с ifram-ом будет не православно ниразу.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню немного:

```
<a href="/item/1" class="modal">Link 1</a>
<a href="/item/2" class="modal">Link 2</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.modal').live(function(e) {
        /*
         * Без preventDefault() будет переход по ссылке
         * Еще можно задавать <a href="#" data-url="/url">
         */
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#popup>iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
        $('#popup').gbxShow(); // GreyBox или jQueryUI.dialog или еще что
    });
</script>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">
<iframe/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

но в версии jquery.1.9  live нужно заменит на ON